# Path to load a file from Javascript in WordPress site

Tags: javascript, wordpress, path

I'm developping a website using WordPress in which I need to include some data-vis made with javascript. I need to load a file containing data in my JS script. Both the script and the data are located in my theme's folder with the following hierarchy :

```
theme
--scripts
----my_script.js
--data
----my_data.csv
```

Say I use d3.js to load the data in my script, using the following code :

```
d3.csv("path/to/data/my_data.csv", function(error, data){
    // Use the data
});
```

What should `path/to/data` be ? I'm very confused. Should it be relative to where the script is ? Or to where the page using the script is ? Relative to the server filesystem, or to the site's domain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I didn't get any answers yet, here's what I ended up doing.

In the page template in which the visualizations are to be displayed, I added the following code to the body :

```
<script>
var theme_URI = "<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>";
</script>
```

This uses a WordPress function to get the path to the current theme, so getting the correct path to my data files is now trivial :

```
d3.csv(theme_URI + "/data/my_data.csv", function(error, data){
    // Use the data
});
```